# How to compute tile offset for different isometric angles?

Tags: tiles, isometric

I am working on an isometric game and the designers want to use a different isometric angle than the default one, where I simply had to do a 2/1 offset based on tile size.

I know what the new isometric angle is, how can I work out the w/h ratio to offset my tiles ?

Comment: Are you aware of the [tangent function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tangent.html) and, incidentally, the [inverse tangent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangent.html)?

Comment: When you find out your answer, you should post it as an answer to this question so future visitors can learn from your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Sam points out](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20942/how-to-compute-tile-offset-for-different-isometric-angles#comment33137_20942), this is essentially all about [trig](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tangent.html).

`tan(angle) = opp/adj` implies that if you know the `angle` and either the width or the height, you can find the other dimension. For example, by rearranging: `opp = adj * arctan(angle)`.